# Saxon 9.8: Which patterns are supported in EXPath File Module function file:list?

Tags: saxon

Good afternoon,

I am working with Java Saxon 9.8.0.4. I would like to use EXPath File Module function "file:list" with its third "pattern" parameter. But I am in doubt, which style of pattern is supported.

I read both [Saxon documentation](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/expath-file/list) and [EXPath documentation](http://expath.org/spec/file#fn.list). But I do not know, which patterns are supported in Saxon 9.8.0.4. It would be great to support regular expression, but I understand it is overkill for most users. I tried several blind tests, but just * and ? wildchars works for me as defined in [EXPath documentation](http://expath.org/spec/file#fn.list).

Yes, I can quite easily do regexp postprocessing in for-each, but to know more about list function could help.

Thank You in advance for Your help, Stepan

P.S: My use-case is to get all files without extension ("test" and not "test.txt") recursively from large and deep directory structure and process all of matching files with XSL-T 3.0. Most of such files have identical fileName and thus I can not do "copy to one folder" pre-processing for Saxon's -s:directory -o:directory one time invocation and invocation of Java (Saxon) for each file is of cource terrible time overhead. So I would like to read all matching files into sequence and process each item of such sequence using for-each (files are text ones and I read them using unparsed-text). And no, GAWK is not solution, as I have all transformation infrastructure from XML to SQL already in XSL-T, because 95 % of files are XMLs.

--ADDED code and explanation below:

Example of my test files.

XML file "a.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="a.xsl"?>
<root/>
```

XSL-T file "a.xsl":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
  xmlns:expathFile="http://expath.org/ns/file"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs saxon"
  version="3.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="list" select="expathFile:list('C:\temp\temp\test\', false(), '^.*$')"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$list">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

My folder "C:\temp\temp\test\" contains 6 test files: "a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt", "e", "f", "g".

But after testing of online Java RegExp tester on "http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html" I have found, that the problem is solely on my side, because Java regular expression behaves little different than PCRE (Perl), sed, gawk regular expressions. So it is my fault and I need to learn Java regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saxon uses the same code for this pattern as for the filter in select="pattern" in collection URIs, which is described at http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!sourcedocs/collections

Extracting the relevant details:

> The pattern used in the select parameter can use glob-like syntax, for
>   example `*.xml` selects all files with extension "xml". More generally,
>   the pattern is converted to a regular expression by prepending `"^"`,
>   appending `"$"`, replacing `"."` by `"\."`, `"*"` by `".*"`, and `"?"` by `".?"`,
>   and it is then used to match the file names appearing in the directory
>   using the Java regular expression rules. So, for example, you can
>   write `?select=*.(xml|xhtml)` to match files with either of these two
>   file extensions. Note however, that special characters used in the URL
>   (that is, characters such as backslash and curly braces that are not
>   allowed in the query part of a URI) must be escaped using the %HH
>   convention. For example, vertical bar needs to be written as %7C. This
>   escaping can be achieved using the encode-for-uri() function.

Note that Saxon's collection() function now also supports match=pattern in the URI, where the pattern is a standard XPath 3.1 regular expression.

Comment: I am very sorry, but even after extensive tries, I am unable to get it to work. My code is: 

<xsl:variable name="list" select="expathFile:list('C:\temp\temp\test', false(), '*')"/> and when I try to change '*' to for example '.*' or '^.*$' it still does not work.

Comment: I fear the wiki system may have corrupted your example code. Please enter it again, this time between backticks.